# Is there any easy proof for this "weak version" of Mazur's theorem on the torsion group of $\mathbb{Q}$-elliptic curves?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, function-fields

I am dealing with the following problem:

> Given a $\mathbb{Q}\left (t\right )$-elliptic curve $E(t)$ with positive rank, prove that for all but finitely many $t_0\in \mathbb{Q}$, the $\mathbb{Q}$-cubic curve that results from replacing $t$ with this particular value $t_0$ is in fact a $\mathbb{Q}$-elliptic curve and has positive rank.

I tried the following: drop the finitely many $t\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that the discriminant of $E(t)$ vanishes. Take a point $P(t)$ of infinite order in $E(\mathbb{Q}(t))$.

Now, suppose we know the following fact, which I shall call "weak Mazur's theorem":

> There exists $M>0$ such that every $\mathbb{Q}$-elliptic curve has at most $M$ torsion points.

Then, if I take the $C+1$ points $iP(t)$ where $i=1,...,M+1$, since they are generically different, two of them coincide just for finitely many $t\in \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore, for all but finitely many $t_0\in \mathbb{Q}$, $E(t_0)$ is an elliptic curve and $P(t_0)$ is a point in $E(t_0)$ with no torsion.

So, I was wondering whether there is an easy way to prove that there exists some universal upper bound for the cardinal of the torsion group of $\mathbb{Q}$-elliptic curves (at least not so difficult as the proof of Mazur's theorem).

Alternatively, we may not be able to find that universal bound, but we may be able to find such a bound not for all elliptic curves, but for the ones that arise in the form $E(t_0)$ for a given $\mathbb{Q}(t)$-elliptic curve (which we know to be finitely generated because of Mordell-Weil's theorem for function fields). What do you think?

Comment: The positive rank part in the question seems non-obvious, don't you have some hints ?

Comment: This is a non-trivial result. First of all, your "weak Mazur's theorem" is really not any easier than Mazur's theorem. Instead, these specialization results are proved using the theory of heights, following Neron, Tate, and Silverman. For example, if P is a point on E(t) of infinite order then the height of the specialization P(t) can be shown to be the h(P(t)) = h(t) + O(1). Since P(t) is torsion iff h(P(t))=0, this implies there are only finitely many such t. See, for example, III.11 of Silverman's book advanced topics in the arithmetic of elliptic curves, Theorem 11.1 in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q(t)$. Let $P_1(t),\ldots,P_r(t)$ be points in $E(\mathbb Q(t))$ that are independent. Then there is an effective (in principle) constant $C=C(E,P_1,\ldots,P_r)$ such that every number in
$$ \bigl\{ t_0\in\mathbb Q : P_1(t_0),\ldots,P_r(t_0)~\text{are dependent} \bigr\} $$
satisfies $h(t_0)\le C$. This follows from a height limit theorem
$$ \lim_{h(t_0)\to\infty} \frac{\hat h_{E_{t_0}}(P(t_0))}{h(t_0)} = \hat h_E(P).\qquad (*) $$
(Tate proved an even stronger height limit estimate, but $(*)$ is true for 1-parameter families of abelian varieties.)

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any material that you would suggest in order to understand better that height limit theorem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The elliptic curve case can be done pretty explicitly, so you really just need to know the basic theory of height functions on varieties. There are lots of places to learn that (e.g., several of my books, Lang's *Diophantine Geometry*, ...)  A specific reference for the stronger result of Tate is *Advanced Topics in the Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, Chapter III, Section 11. The limit formula $(*)$ for abelian varieties uses more machinery and is  proved in Heights and the specialization map for families of abelian varieties, *J. Reine Angew. Math.* **342** (1983), 197-211.

Comment: Probably the most down-to-earth proof of $(*)$ just for elliptic curves, i.e., using explicit formulas and as little algebraic geometry as possible, is in my thesis, but it never got published, since it was just a special case of the abelian variety result, and weaker than Tate's result for elliptic curves.